# How to have dynamic height for Collection View cell's contentView when Collection View is inside a TableView cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `CollectionView` present inside a `TableViewCell`. The collection view is configured to have horizontal scroll direction with 2 items in one single row.

I want the items to be of equal width and together to take up the entire `TableViewCell`'s width with a spacing of 5 pixels between cells. I was able to get this using the following code in my `TableViewCell`.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int collectionViewWidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width;
    return CGSizeMake(collectionViewWidth/2 - 2.5, (CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame)));
}
```

The collection view cell has just one label. However, the text this label contains can vary in length and can end up having in multiple lines. I want to know how can this be achieved.

I have set the number of lines to 0 for the label in storyboard. And from the controller where I have this table view, I have set the following in `viewDidLoad` -

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 210.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

In the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, I have -

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

So far, I tried adding the following code in `CollectionViewCell` but this did not help -

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes {

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attr = [super preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:layoutAttributes]; //Must be called
    CGRect frame = attr.frame;
    frame.size.height = layoutAttributes.size.height; //Key here
    attr.frame = frame;
    return attr;
}
```

I am not sure what additional thing I need to do in here to achieve what I want to.

Adding a snapshot of what is expected.

[image]

Comment: Let's see... You have TWO "cells" and you want them to take up *only* the visible width of the table? Sounds like using a `UICollectionView` is the wrong tool. Why not just use two labels? Or two views, each with a label? Maybe show a picture of what you want...

Comment: @DonMag I have added the snap of what I want. It is basically a table view with first three rows as one prototype TableViewCell. The next two is a different prototype TableViewCell which has a collection view inside its content view. I could use two views but I went with collection view because the number of cells in fourth row can increase from 2 to 6 in horizontal direction.

Comment: Using a collection view is going to be a bit tricky... In order to dynamically size the **height** of the collection view, you have to know the max height of the cells. However, collection views don't render or calculate cells that are not visible. You may need to loop through your data and calculate the bounding boxes for each cell's text, and then set the constraint constant for the height of the collection view.